# How to retrieve information from the tokio-proto connection handshake?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm figuring out how to use the `tokio-proto` crate, particularly on the handshake made when a connection is established. I've got the example from the [official documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/going-deeper-tokio/handshake/) working:

```
impl<T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + 'static> ClientProto<T> for ClientLineProto {
    type Request = String;
    type Response = String;

    /// `Framed<T, LineCodec>` is the return value of `io.framed(LineCodec)`
    type Transport = Framed<T, line::LineCodec>;
    type BindTransport = Box<Future<Item = Self::Transport, Error = io::Error>>;

    fn bind_transport(&self, io: T) -> Self::BindTransport {
        // Construct the line-based transport
        let transport = io.framed(line::LineCodec);

        // Send the handshake frame to the server.
        let handshake = transport.send("You ready?".to_string())
            // Wait for a response from the server, if the transport errors out,
            // we don't care about the transport handle anymore, just the error
            .and_then(|transport| transport.into_future().map_err(|(e, _)| e))
            .and_then(|(line, transport)| {
                // The server sent back a line, check to see if it is the
                // expected handshake line.
                match line {
                    Some(ref msg) if msg == "Bring it!" => {
                        println!("CLIENT: received server handshake");
                        Ok(transport)
                    }
                    Some(ref msg) if msg == "No! Go away!" => {
                        // At this point, the server is at capacity. There are a
                        // few things that we could do. Set a backoff timer and
                        // try again in a bit. Or we could try a different
                        // remote server. However, we're just going to error out
                        // the connection.

                        println!("CLIENT: server is at capacity");
                        let err = io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "server at capacity");
                        Err(err)
                    }
                    _ => {
                        println!("CLIENT: server handshake INVALID");
                        let err = io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "invalid handshake");
                        Err(err)
                    }
                }
            });

        Box::new(handshake)
    }
}
```

But the official docs only mention a handshake without stateful information. Is there a common way to retrieve and store useful data from the handshake?

For example, if during the handshake (in the first message after the connection is established) the server sends some key that should be used later by the client, how should the `ClientProto` implementation look into that key? And where should it be stored?

Comment: I think I must be missing something — isn't your variable `handshake` the "key" you are looking for? Add it's already being returned from this function, so you just... *use* it?

Comment: `handshake` variable that is returned from the `bind_transport()` is a future that contains handshake procedure that hasn't been executed yet. I need to read some key value during this handshake and use it in the requests that will go later from this client. Basically, I need to retrieve and store some value after the handshake future will complete. I don't see any way to do this except implementing my own `BindClient` trait for my protocol, and I'm not sure it's the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fields to `ClientLineProto`, so this should work:

```
pub struct ClientLineProto {
    handshakes: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>
}
```

And then you can reference it and store data as needed:

```
let mut handshakes = self.handshakes.lock();
handshakes.insert(handshake_key, "Blah blah handshake data")
```

This sort of access would work in `bind_transport()` for storing things. Then when you create the `Arc::Mutex::HashMap` in your `main()` function and you will have access to the whole thing in the `serve()` method as well, which means you can pass it in to the Service object instantiation and then the handshakes will be available during `call()`.